# POSIX's FTW structure members - what do they tell us?

Tags: c, posix

Posix defines in `ftw.h` a structure `FTW` like this ([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ftw.h.html)):

> The `<ftw.h>` header shall define the `FTW` structure, which shall include
> at least the following members:
>
> `int base`
> `int level`

But Posix does not tell what `base` and `level` represent. So what do these integers represent or in other words what do they tell us?

Comment: You have to also read [the manual page for the `nftw` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/nftw.html) (which uses that structure).

Comment: I did also read that. That is what brought me to FTW structure in the first place... But nothing useful is there.

Comment: From the linked `nftw` reference: "The value of **base** is the offset of the object's filename in the pathname passed as the first argument to fn(). The value of **level** indicates depth relative to the root of of the walk, where the root level is 0." (emphasis not mine). The quote is regarding the arguments passed to the callback.

Comment: How could I miss this... Thank you everybody! It is all in the standard.